# Django 3 - Model.save() when providing a default for the primary key

Tags: python, django, django-3.0

I'm working on upgrading my project from Django 2 to Django 3, I have read their [release notes of Django 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/3.0/#django-3-0-release-notes) and there is [a point](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/3.0/#backwards-incompatible-changes-in-3-0) that I don't really understand what it will impact to my current project. Here they say:

[image]

As I understand, if we try to call `Model.save()`, it would always create a new record instead of updating if the model is an existing record. For example:

```
car = Car.objects.first()
car.name = 'Honda'
car.save() # does it INSERT or UPDATE? I suspect it is an "INSERT" statement as their explanation and "UPDATE" statement in Django 2.
```

I have had an experimented and it is still the same behaviour as Django 2, not sure what they mean.

```
In [5]: u = User.objects.first()                                                                                                                                                                          
(0.001) SELECT "accounts_user"."id", "accounts_user"."password", "accounts_user"."last_login", "accounts_user"."is_superuser", "accounts_user"."username", "accounts_user"."first_name", "accounts_user"."last_name", "accounts_user"."is_staff", "accounts_user"."is_active", "accounts_user"."date_joined", "accounts_user"."email", "accounts_user"."avatar", "accounts_user"."last_location"::bytea, "accounts_user"."uuid", "accounts_user"."country", "accounts_user"."city", "accounts_user"."phone" FROM "accounts_user" ORDER BY "accounts_user"."id" ASC LIMIT 1; args=()

In [6]: u.save()                                                                                                                                                                                          
(0.006) UPDATE "accounts_user" SET "password" = 'pbkdf2_sha256_sha512$180000$FbFcNuPMrOZ6$GwIftEo+7+OpsORwn99lycye46aJn/aJNAtc50N478Y=', "last_login" = NULL, "is_superuser" = false, "username" = 'email0@mail.com', "first_name" = 'Noah', "last_name" = 'Spencer', "is_staff" = false, "is_active" = true, "date_joined" = '2020-05-12T07:06:20.605650+00:00'::timestamptz, "email" = 'email0@mail.com', "avatar" = 'account/user_avatar/example_HseJquC.jpg', "last_location" = NULL, "uuid" = 'f6992866-e476-409e-9f1b-098afadce5b7'::uuid, "country" = NULL, "city" = NULL, "phone" = NULL WHERE "accounts_user"."id" = 1; args=('pbkdf2_sha256_sha512$180000$FbFcNuPMrOZ6$GwIftEo+7+OpsORwn99lycye46aJn/aJNAtc50N478Y=', False, 'email0@mail.com', 'Noah', 'Spencer', False, True, datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 12, 7, 6, 20, 605650, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'email0@mail.com', 'account/user_avatar/example_HseJquC.jpg', UUID('f6992866-e476-409e-9f1b-098afadce5b7'), 1)
```

Update:

```
In [38]: u1 = User.objects.first()                                                                                                                                                                        
(0.000) SELECT "accounts_user"."id", "accounts_user"."password", "accounts_user"."last_login", "accounts_user"."is_superuser", "accounts_user"."username", "accounts_user"."first_name", "accounts_user"."last_name", "accounts_user"."is_staff", "accounts_user"."is_active", "accounts_user"."date_joined", "accounts_user"."email", "accounts_user"."avatar", "accounts_user"."last_location"::bytea, "accounts_user"."uuid", "accounts_user"."country", "accounts_user"."city", "accounts_user"."phone" FROM "accounts_user" ORDER BY "accounts_user"."id" ASC LIMIT 1; args=()

In [39]: u1.pk                                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[39]: 1

In [40]: u2 = User(pk=1)                                                                                                                                                                                  

In [41]: u2.email = 'email@email.com'                                                                                                                                                                     

In [42]: u2.save()                                                                                                                                                                                        
(0.006) UPDATE "accounts_user" SET "password" = '', "last_login" = NULL, "is_superuser" = false, "username" = 'email@email.com', "first_name" = '', "last_name" = '', "is_staff" = false, "is_active" = true, "date_joined" = '2020-05-13T01:20:47.718449+00:00'::timestamptz, "email" = 'email@email.com', "avatar" = '', "last_location" = NULL, "uuid" = '89ba0924-03a7-44d2-bc6d-5fd2dcb0de0b'::uuid, "country" = NULL, "city" = NULL, "phone" = NULL WHERE "accounts_user"."id" = 1; args=('', False, 'email@email.com', '', '', False, True, datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 13, 1, 20, 47, 718449, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'email@email.com', '', UUID('89ba0924-03a7-44d2-bc6d-5fd2dcb0de0b'), 1)
```

Comment: Rather than posting images please quote text from docs

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Consider this example. Suppose we have a simple model as

```
CONSTANT = 10


def foo_pk_default():
    return CONSTANT


class Foo(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, default=foo_pk_default)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

The main thing I have done in this example is, **I did set a default callable function for Primary Keys**. Also, I returned only a single value from the function, for the sake of demonstration.

```
## Django 2.2
In [5]: foo_instance_1 = Foo(name='foo_name_1')

In [6]: foo_instance_1.save()

In [7]: print(foo_instance_1.__dict__)
{'_state': , 'id': 10, 'name': 'foo_name_1'}

In [8]: foo_instance_2 = Foo(name='foo_name_2')

In [9]: foo_instance_2.save()

In [10]: print(foo_instance_2.__dict__)
{'_state': , 'id': 10, 'name': 'foo_name_2'}

## Django 3.X
In [6]: foo_instance_1 = Foo(name='foo_name_1')

In [7]: foo_instance_1.save()

In [8]: print(foo_instance_1.__dict__)
{'_state': , 'id': 10, 'name': 'foo_name_1'}

In [9]: foo_instance_2 = Foo(name='foo_name_2')

In [10]: foo_instance_2.save()
# Raised "IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: music_foo.id"
```

### Conclusion

In **`Django<3.0`**, the **`Model.save()`** will do an ***update or insert operation*** if there is a PK value associated with the model instance whereas in **`Django>=3.0`**, only perform an ***insert operation*** hence the `UNIQUE constraint failed` exception.

### Impact of this change in the current project

Since this Django change is only applicable when a ***new instance is created*** and we usually don't set any default value functions for Primary Keys.

In short, this change will not make any problem unless you are providing default value during model instance creation.

Comment: This is a perfect answer. Thanks!

I will award the bounty once it is available (it says there are 17 hours left).

Comment: Any idea _why_ the Django project has made this change?  It breaks quite a lot of code for me.

Answer (score 0):

It should be read carefully

> no longer attempts to find a row when saving **a new Model instance**
>   and a **default value for the primary key is provided**,

So in case you are going to **create new object** with **id that is already in database** it would now **fail** instead of having behavior similar to update_or_create as it will now preform `INSERT` statement instead of `UPDATE`

Comment: It seems not like that, it still performs an UPDATE statement. Please see my update in the question post for the example.